# Unique ID Prefix appended to every uploaded image through Forminator

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-shortcode

I am using a WordPress hook to create a new post after Forminator form submission. In the Forminator form, there is a file upload field from which the users can upload images. I want these images to be used as a thumbnail for the newly created post after the submission. I use the following code in my theme's functions.php file:

```
add_action('forminator_form_after_handle_submit', 'create_post_with_image_and_redirect', 10, 2);
add_action('forminator_form_after_save_entry', 'create_post_with_image_and_redirect', 10, 2);

function create_post_with_image_and_redirect($form_id, $response) {
    // Check if the form ID matches
    if ($form_id == 761) {
        // Get the uploaded image file
        $uploaded_image = $_FILES['upload-1'];

        // Check if an image was uploaded
        if (!empty($uploaded_image['name'])) {
            // Define the upload directory
            $upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
            $upload_path = $upload_dir['path'] . '/';

            // Generate a unique filename
            $image_filename = $uploaded_image['name'];

            // Move the uploaded image to the upload directory
            $image_path = $upload_path . $image_filename;
            move_uploaded_file($uploaded_image['name'], $image_path);

            // Create the post title.
            $post_title = 'Test-Title';

            $post_content .= "\nimage path: " . $image_path . "\nfilepath: " . $image_filename;
            // Create a new post
            $post_data = array(
                'post_title'    => $post_title,
                'post_content'  => $post_content,
                'post_status'   => 'publish',
                'post_type'     => 'post'
            );

            // Insert the post into the database
            $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);

            // Attach the image to the post
            if ($post_id && !is_wp_error($post_id)) {
                $attachment = array(
                    'post_title'     => $image_filename,
                    'post_content'   => '',
                    'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                    'post_mime_type' => $uploaded_image['type'],
                );

                $attachment_id = wp_insert_attachment($attachment, $image_path, $post_id);
                if (!is_wp_error($attachment_id)) {
                    require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php');
                    $attachment_data = wp_generate_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $image_path);
                    wp_update_attachment_metadata($attachment_id, $attachment_data);
                    set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $attachment_id); // Set the image as featured image
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The behavior is the following:
a unique id prefix is appended to the image's name and causes an issue.
Example:
User uploads an image with the following name: Screenshot-2023-07-25-171253.png
Then the user submits the form.
The following error messages are received in php-error.log:

```
[05-Sep-2023 12:21:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  getimagesize(/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/Screenshot 2023-07-25 171253.png): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-includes/media.php on line 5307
[05-Sep-2023 12:21:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  exif_imagetype(/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/Screenshot 2023-07-25 171253.png): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3268
[05-Sep-2023 12:21:47 UTC] PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(/var/www/html/wp-content/uploads/Screenshot 2023-07-25 171253.png): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3291
```

When I look into the directory /var/www/html/wp-content/uploads, I see the following:

```
ll -t
total 1820
drwxr-xr-x 6 www-data www-data  12288 Sep  5 00:36 ./
-rw-r--r-- 1 www-data www-data   2052 Sep  5 00:36 hNOIpKCMymwC-Screenshot-2023-07-25-171253.png
...
```

The following unique id prefix `hNOIpKCMymwC-` was appended to the original name of the image.
I did some research and saw that Forminator Plugin appends this unique id to prevent overwriting an image if two users happen to upload an image with the same name. However, I need to find a solution to this so that I can properly use the uploaded image as thumbnail and find a way to get the value of this unique identifier and use it in my code.